# Change object format

Tags: javascript, node.js, object

So I have an object that has data in this form:

```
{key1: val1, key2: val2}
```

And I want to somehow convert to something like below:

```
{first: {key1:[], val1:[]},
second: {key2:[], val2:[]} };
```

I tried doing

```
object = {key1: val1, key2: val2};
var array = {};
var cc=0;
for (var prop in object){
    var ob_prop = object[prop];
    if(cc) array['first'] = {prop:[], ob_prop:[]};
    else array['second'] = {prop:[],ob_prop:[]};
    cc++;
}
```

but instead I get

```
{ second: { prop: [], ob_prop: [] },
first: { prop: [], ob_prop: [] } }
```

Comment: I dont understand why I was down-voted, I explained clearly what I want and what I have tried.

Comment: please add the source object and what you like to get from it.

Comment: I would assume the down vote may have been due to the lack of research. Posting should thoroughly research topic, then post what you have tried and/or found. In regards to your posting, perhaps the question was down voted because the answer can be found quite easily. In support of your comment, I think people should leave comments if they down vote. So here is one up vote for you.

Comment: Thank you for the upvote! In my defense I should add I searched for an answer (perhaps I didnt do it right) and because I couldn't find, so I opened a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments by Felix Kling, try: `array['first'] = {[prop]:[], [ob_prop]:[]};`

Comment: nope that leads to a compilation error, as naturally it cant set property key1 of undefined.

Comment: If you assume that the OP can use `for/of` loops, then using computed properties would probably be the simpler solution: `{[prop]:[], [ob_prop]:[]}`.

Comment: Thank you, all I had to add was the `[`, `]` for it to work, so I guess indeed an idiotic question worthy of downvoting, so instead of `{prop:[], ob_prop:[]}` -> `{[prop]:[], [ob_prop]:[]}`

Comment: Note that this is an ES6 feature, so older browsers may not support it.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind thanks.